# Resource directory is not included in output directory in Intellij Idea CE 2018.2.1

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I recently upgrade my intellij idea into intellij idea 2018.2.1, however when I tried to run test, I got this error log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:770)
    at com.google.common.io.Resources$UrlByteSource.<init>(Resources.java:67)
    at com.google.common.io.Resources$UrlByteSource.<init>(Resources.java:62)
    at com.google.common.io.Resources.asByteSource(Resources.java:56)
    at com.google.common.io.Resources.asCharSource(Resources.java:87)
    at com.google.common.io.Resources.toString(Resources.java:111)
```

Just wondering what possible adjustment settings that need to be done. In my case I already use java plugin which actually said that: this resources directly will be included under [`out/classes`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput:resourcesDir). Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you use Maven or Gradle? Do you face this issue with every project?

Comment: I'm using gradle

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

`sourceSets {
    main {
        output.resourcesDir = file('out/production/classes')
        output.classesDir = file('out/production/classes')
    }
    test {
        output.resourcesDir = file('out/test/classes')
        output.classesDir = file('out/test/classes')
    }
}`